# Classical mapping of kicked Harper model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, poincare-recurrence

The Hamiltonian of [kicked Harper model](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kicked_Harper_model) is given by 
$$
H=K\cos(p)+\left[K\cos(x)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-n)\right]
$$
where $\delta$ function term represents the effect of very narrow pulses of an external field which kicks the system only at $t=\ldots,(n-1), n, (n+1)\ldots$ and between two neighbouring kick Hamiltonian reduces to $H=K\cos(p).$

How to derive the classical map from $(x_n,p_n)$ to $(x_{n+1},p_{n+1})$ after $t = n$ and show that it is area preserving. Also need to identify the fixed points and identify the stabilities.

I am confused that the Hamiltonian is in dimensionless form also my concepts related to mapping are quite weak. Can anybody explain, so that I could learn?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to derive the solution but will observe that is type of *parametric resonance* problem is discussed in many (more advanced) textbook on classical mechanics.  The solution is given
[here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kicked_Harper_model) for instance, if you need to check your calculation.

Given the solution:
$$
p_{n+1}=p_n+K\sin(x_n)\, ,\qquad x_{n+1}=x_n−K\sin(p_{n+1})\, ,
$$
it is easy to show that the area is preserved using exterior calculus. Area preservation means the area 2-form
$d p_{n+1}\wedge dx_{n+1}=d p_n\wedge dx_n$.  Thus
\begin{align}
dp_{n+1}&=dp_n+K\cos(x_n)dx_n\, ,\\
 dx_{n+1}&= dx_n-K\cos(p_{n+1})dp_{n+1}\, ,\\
&=dx_n-K\cos(p_{n+1})\left(dp_n+K\cos(x_n)dx_n\right)\, .
\end{align}
With this, and remembering $dp_k\wedge dp_k=dx_k\wedge dx_k=0$ and
$dx_k\wedge dp_k=-dp_k\wedge dx_k$ one rapidly finds
\begin{align}
d p_{n+1}\wedge dx_{n+1}&= dp_n\wedge dx_n(1-K^2\cos(p_{n+1})\cos(x_n))\\
&\qquad -K^2\cos(p_{n+1})\cos(x_n) dx_n\wedge dp_n\, ,\\
&=dp_n\wedge dx_n\, ,
\end{align}
which shows the area-preserving property of the map.